# Xamarin iOS bind library with blocks

Tags: ios, xamarin, objective-c-blocks, infobip

I'm trying to bind Infobips Objective-C library to Xamarin. But I get stuck on this block:

```
+ (void)shareLocation:(CLLocation *)userLocation withBlock:(IPResponseBlock)block;
```

I've never used Blocks in Objective-C and don't really understand how this should be mapped to C#.

Can anybody help me figure this out?

Regards//Lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me break it down for you:

[image]

Notice how similar is the syntax between lambdas and blocks:

```
(args) => {
//  implementation code
};
```

---

```
(void) = ^{
        NSLog(@"This is a block");
    };
```

Now, for the binding part, Xamarin provides a easy to use documentation: [Binding Objective-C Libraries](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/)

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand now and got one step further in my btouch build.